# Is there a URL is can use to search for an image and returns the first found image?

Tags: search-engine

I want to use a URL to search for a car by its name & model and have the first image hit returned. Is there a way to achieve this? I've looked at Google & YAHOO, but they return more than I wish for.

All I need is my request to be redirected to the URL of the first found image....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to obtain a relevant imagine (not equal to the top hit on Google), is:

http://( Type any keyword here ).jpg.to

For example:

- http://dog.jpg.to
- http://biting_dog.jpg.to
- http://mercedes_benz.jpg.to

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with a java .net client when trying to fill an ImageView in android for example. I think it's because of the ".to". How can I avoid this?

Comment: not reliable enough, I wouldn't recommend this. check <http://facebook.jpg.to> for example!

Comment: What do you mean by reliability? Availability or quality of image? Both of those appear to provide relevant images.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore (unsurprisingly, 12 years later) :-)

Answer (score 3):

I know you mentioned Yahoo didn't work, however we are utilizing a Yahoo API in a very similar context successfully. Check out the [BOSS image search API](http://developer.yahoo.com/search/boss/boss_guide/Submit_Image_Queries.html). One of the reasons we originally went with BOSS was that it does not have any daily limits. The image search API also lets you filter, indicate size, and more. The [results are returned](http://developer.yahoo.com/search/boss/boss_guide/response_image.html) in XML.

With all that being said, if we had to do it over, we would go the [Bing API route](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd250942.aspx), as Bing has a brighter future than Yahoo and has very similar, if not better, API. It looks like it can return results in XML, JSON, and SOAP.

EDIT:

After seeing you were JUST looking for a URL, I tried all the three major search engines and the following URL was the closest I could come to what you decribed: http://www.bing.com/images/search?q=car&view=detail&first=1

I'm afraid the only way to get exactly what you are looking for 100% client side would to be to utilize the Bing API with a jsonp result and then manipulate the DOM via Javascript. [Check out this code sample for a rough start.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd251094.aspx)

Comment: Thanx. I know how to parse. I was hoping to find an easy way out without parsing. I need it in an iPhone project. I guess there is no way without parsing the results of an API call to google/yahoo/bing.

Comment: I went with your BING suggestion. It was the easiest.

Answer (score 1):

Bing has a pretty easy to use [web search API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd250942.aspx). You can pass it a URL with various parameters and it will return an [XML result](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd250862.aspx). The two parameters you would be interested in would be SourceType (=Image) and ImageRequest.Count (=1).

However, you would need to parse the XML because it won't just give you back the image data.

Comment: Yep, I know about the API's that require parsing. I need the image search URL to put in the src element of an iFrame to show the image. Some kind of google's I feel lucky but for images.

Comment: In that case... write your own HTTP handler that uses the Bing search API on the server and returns a 302 redirect to the first returned image.

Comment: I think I need to drop my wish and just parse the results of an API call to google/yahoo/bing in my iPhone project. Thanx anyway.

Answer (score 0):

A few options (which worked in 2023):

https://loremflickr.com/320/240/dog

https://p-hold.com/kitten/100/100